# Apache Reverse Proxy not working

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a blog hosted on a remote server than our front end. I want to point our http://domain.com/blog into http://blog.domain.com which is where our current blog resides (the virtual host leads to a different machine).

- So: http://www.domain.com/blog/my-post
- Should discretely point to: http://blog.domain.com/my-post

I've tried several ways to do this, but to no avail:

```
<Location "/blog">
    # Blog proxy
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /blog http://blog.domain.com # with/without /blog
    ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.domain.com # with/without /blog
</Location>
```

Also outside `<Location>`:

```
# Blog proxy
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.domain.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.domain.com
```

Also tried with/without trailing slashes.

Can't get it to work.

I made sure the `.htaccess` in the http://domain.com/ root is ignoring any rewriterules pointing to `$/?blog` by using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?blog`, but still nothing. I just get a 404. The directory shouldn't exist, should it?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try this guide http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Answer (score 1):

To create a redirect like this you need to configure a apache2 vhost proxy to listen on blog.example.com and to pass the requests to http://example.com/blog

You do this like this:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://example.com/blog
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/blog
</VirtualHost>`

Note: you need to enable the proxy module for apache2 (`sudo a2enmod proxy`). You need to restart apache2 after enabling the module (`sudo service apache2 restart`).